# Vitest - How to test that asyncThunk was called in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk, vitest

I have an `App.tsx` that looks as follows:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react'

import { useAppDispatch } from './app/hooks'
import { fetchCoordinates } from './features/location/locationSlice'

const App = () => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch()

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchCoordinates())
  }, [dispatch])

  return (
    <div>placeholder</div>
  )
}

export default App
```

And now I want to test that `fetchCoordinates()` are called in my `App.test.tsx` test, and so I wrote this test file:

```
import { describe, it, expect, beforeEach } from 'vitest'
import { render } from '@testing-library/react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

import App from '../App'
import store from '../app/store'
import { fetchCoordinates } from '../features/location/locationSlice'

describe('App', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>,
    )
  })

  it('calls fetchCoordinates on mount', () => {
    expect(fetchCoordinates).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
  })
})
```

But when I run the test it fails with `TypeError: [Function actionCreator] is not a spy or a call to a spy!` and I can't figure out why.

For reference, this is what the `fetchCoordinates()` function looks like:

```
import { createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

import { setLoading, showAlert, hideAlert } from '../shared/commonSlice'
import Coordinates from '../../models/Coordinates'

export const fetchCoordinates = createAsyncThunk(
  'location/fetchCoordinates',
  async (_, { dispatch }) => {
    return new Promise<Coordinates>((resolve, reject) => {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        position => resolve(position.coords),
        err => reject(err),
        { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 },
      )
    })
  },
)
```